# Возникает ошибка с ограничением доступа к профилю для незарег. пользователей

Tags: php, авторизация, регистрация

Пишу сайт с регистрацией и авторизацией. Пытаюсь ограничить доступ к профилю для незарегистрированных пользователей. В файле **profile.php** написал следующий код:

session_start();

```
if (!$_SESSION['user']) header("Location: index.php");
```

в файле, отвечающий за авторизацию, вот это:

session_start();
require_once 'connection.php';

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$check_user = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users_onlycash` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($check_user) > 0) {

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_user);

    $_SESSION['user'] = [
        "id" => $user['id'],
        "login" => $user['login'],
        "password" => $user['password'],
        "balans" => $user['balans']
    ];

    header("Location: profile.php");

} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
    header("Location: login_page.php");
```

в итоге при входе в профиль незарегистрированный пользователь не попадает на главную и код не работает. Также если похожий код добавить на страницу со входом, то там пишет "неизвестный ключ ['user]"

помогите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

В проверке попробуйте использовать функцию `isset()`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[“user”])) ...
```

Для дебага юзайте `var_dump()` и ошибка быстро найдётся